# Asynchronous behavior when sorting with attrgetter vs. methodcaller on attributes and methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

Imagine I have a class `Test` with an attribute `foo` and a method `getbar()`.

```
from operator import attrgetter, methodcaller

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.name = name

    def getbar(self):
        """ bar is same value as foo, so should sort identically"""
        self.bar = self.foo 

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

I will make a few objects, and then sort them based on values of `foo` and `getbar`, using attrgetter.

```
 objs = [Test('a', 5), Test('b', 9), Test('c',20), Test('d', 50)  

 print 'attrgetter: foo', sorted(objs, key=attrgetter('foo'))
 print 'attrgetter: bar', sorted(objs, key=attrgetter('getbar'))

 >>>attrgetter: foo [a, b, c, d]
 >>>attrgetter: bar [b, a, c, d]
```

**getbar()** is not being sorted correctly.  Fair enough, but why does`attrgetter` accept a method and not throw an error if it's not going to sort correctly?

Using `methodcaller` to sort will raise an error if an attribute is passed..., so why doesn't `attrgetter` raise an error upon receiving a method?  Can someone explain this discrepancy to me?  It seems like they should be symmetric.

```
print 'methodcaller: bar', sorted(objs, key=methodcaller('getbar'))
print 'methodcaller: foo', sorted(objs, key=methodcaller('foo'))

>>>methodcaller: bar [a, b, c, d]
>>>methodcaller: foo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2249624f153f> in <module>()
     19 
     20 print 'methodcaller: bar', sorted(objs, key=methodcaller('getbar'))
---> 21 print 'methodcaller: foo', sorted(objs, key=methodcaller('foo'))

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using `methodcaller` to sort will raise an error if an attribute is passed..., so why doesn't `attrgetter` raise an error upon receiving a method?

Because in Python, instance methods *are* attributes. The only difference is that the value that is returned is a bound method which is then usually called.

If you want to have similar behavior with both then you should create a property that returns the return value of the method and then get that attribute from the instance.